# How to retain search results when clicking browser's back button - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, caching, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 3 MVC application that has a Customers tab in addition to the Home tab. On the Customers tab there is an input box where the user adds a search criterion (number of days) and a Search button. When the button is clicked then a list of Customer Ids is shown underneath (using jQuery and a Partial View). When the user clicks on a customer Id then the customer information is shown in a different page. However when I click on the browser's back button or on the 'Customers' tab then the criterion added and the search results disappear.

I have tried using the ResponseCache attribute to retain the search results but I could not make it work. I have also tried using the Cache Tag Helper but again was not successful. Anyone can help?

CustomersController

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
      private readonly DbContext _context;

      public CustomersController(DbContext context)
      {
          _context= context;
      }

      public IActionResult Index()
      {
          return View();
      }

      public IActionResult DisplayCustomerIdList(string searchText)
      {
          List<CustomerDetailViewModel> customers = _context.GetAll().ToList();

          CustomerIndexViewModel model = new CustomerIndexViewModel()
          {
              Customers = customers
          };

          return PartialView("_CustomerIdListView", model);
      }

      public IActionResult Detail(decimal? Id)
      {
          Customer customer = _context.GetCustomerById(Id);

          CustomerDetailViewModel model = new CustomerDetailViewModel(customer);

          return View(model);
      }

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Customers Page";
}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayCustomerIdList", "Customers")';

    $('#search').click(function () {
        var keyWord = $('#NumberOfDays').val();
        $('#searchResults').load(url, { searchText: keyWord });
        return false;
    })

    </script>
}


<body>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 w-50">
        <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Number of days" autocomplete="off" id="NumberOfDays">
        <button id="search" class="btn btn-outline-info mb-2">Search</button>
    </div>

    <div id="searchResults"></div>

</body>
```

_CustomerIdListView.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.CustomerIndexViewModel

<div class="card border-info mb-3 shadow" style="width:220px; height: 625px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="card-header">Customer Ids</div>
    <div class="list-group">
        @foreach (CustomerDetailViewModel customerdetails in Model.Customers)
        {
            <a asp-controller="Customers" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@customerdetails.CustomerId" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                @customerdetails.CustomerId
            </a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Detail.cshtml

```
@model MyProject.Models.CustomerDetailViewModel

<h3>Customer Information</h3>

<ul>
    <li>@Model.CustomerId</li>
    <li>@Model.FullName</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the search via a GET request (rather than post). That way, the actual URL the user is sent to includes the query.

```
<form action="/foo" method="get">
```

Comment: How can I still show the search results at the same page using a GET request?

Comment: It wasn't clear that you were making an AJAX request. Essentially you still must change the URL, since that's what determines what the user goes "back" to. However, JS has a History API you can utilize for this, without having to actually change the page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why this was not working and thought to add it here in case someone else has the same issue.

It turns out that the jQuery .load() method creates a POST request when the input parameter is an object (and a GET request when it is a String). So, because the ResponseCache attribute does not work with POST requests, the caching was not working.

Comment: Hello, So what is your fix?